# Python3 RLE Character

Tags: python, run-length-encoding

I'm learning python and I have this code that compresses and decompresses with blanks and would like to know how I could get the letters, that is, take only characters and not white spaces

The stack overflow wants me to add more comments about my question with the code so I'm writing this just ignore this part ok?

```
archive = open('text.txt', 'r')
archiveS = archive.read()

archiveC = open('./archive2.txt', 'w')
archiveD = open ('./archive3.txt', "w")

list = []
compressed = ''
uncompressed = ''

for line in archiveS:
       for ch in line:
           list.append(ch)

white = 0
text = len(list)

if white < text:
    for letter in archiveS:
        if letter == ' ':
            white += 1

        elif white > 0:
            compressed += 'x' + str(white)

            white = 0
        if letter!=' ':
            compressed+=letter

    archiveC.write(compressed)

print(archiveC)

print(compressed)


counter = 0

lst  = list2 = []

for letter in compressed:

    if letter == 'x':
       pass

    elif letter.isnumeric():

        num = int(letter)
        list2.append(' '*num)

        uncompressed = lst

    else:
        list2.append(letter)


strDes =''.join(uncompressed)

print(uncompressed, 'descompressed')

archiveD.write(strDes)
archive.close()
archiveC.close()
archiveD.close()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Is your program not working as intended?

Comment: @DanielWalker Thanks, in fact the program works however I would like it to take letters instead of blanks